# Can't mock module import in Cypress Vue component tests

Tags: vue.js, mocking, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I'm new to [Cypress component testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/introduction), but I was able to set it up easily for my Vue project. I'm currently investigating if we should replace Jest with Cypress to test our Vue components and I love it so far, there is only one major feature I'm still missing: mocking modules. I first tried with `cy.stub()`, but it simply didn't work which could make sense since I'm not trying to mock the actual module in Node.js, but the module imported within Webpack.

To solve the issue, I tried to use [rewiremock](https://github.com/theKashey/rewiremock) which is able to mock Webpack modules, but I'm getting an error when running the test:

[image]

I forked the examples from Cypress and set up Rewiremock in [this commit](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-component-examples/commit/ab65dbb51f0dfcb01df9d8cdfe56b529d7e52f42). Not sure what I'm doing wrong to be honest.

I really need to find a way to solve it otherwise, we would simply stop considering Cypress and just stick to Jest. If using Rewiremock is not the way, how am I suppose to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? we're also using cypress component testing + rewiremock but with React, and we're encountering the same exact error

Comment: @jchi2241 I didn't unfortunately since Jest won against Cypress when we evaluated the two solutions. Please share if you find something.

Comment: We found a solution -- instead of using rewiremock to mock modules, we aliased the dependencies we wanted to mock in the Cypress webpack config with [webpack aliases][1]. Instead of loading the module, webpack would intercept and load a mock file. In that file we'd have functions that would reset the internal mock that we'd call before each test. e.g., `let mock; export function setupMock(...) { mock = { ... } } export default mock;` [1]: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias

Comment: Yeah I also thought about it, but it's not really what I'm looking for unfortunately since this would mock it for all tests and quite often, we need to mock a module for a specific test only which is done very easily with Jest.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to adjust the Vue component to make it more testable, the function can be mocked as a component property.

**Webpack**

When vue-loader processes `HelloWorld.vue`, it evaluates `getColorOfFruits()` and sets the data property, so to mock the function here, you need a webpack re-writer like rewiremock.

```js
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      colorOfFruits: getColorOfFruits(),   // during compile time
    };
  },
  ...
```

**Vue created hook**

If you initiialize `colorOfFruits` in the `created()` hook, you can stub the `getColorOfFruits` function after import but prior to mounting.

**HelloWorld.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ colorOfFruits.apple }}</h2>
    <p>
    ...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { getColorOfFruits } from "@/helpers/fruit.js";  

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  getColorOfFruits,          // add this function to the component for mocking
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      colorOfFruits: {}      // initialized empty here
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.colorOfFruits = this.$options.colorOfFruits;  // reference function saved above
  }
});
</script>
```

**HelloWorld.spec.js**

```js
import { mount } from "@cypress/vue";
import HelloWorld from "./HelloWorld.vue";

it("mocks an apple", () => {

  const getMockFruits = () => {
    return {
      apple: "green",
      orange: "purple",
    }
  }

  HelloWorld.getColorOfFruits = getMockFruits;

  mount(HelloWorld, {                      // created() hook called as part of mount()
    propsData: {
      msg: "Hello Cypress!",
    },
  });

  cy.get("h1").contains("Hello Cypress!");

  cy.get("h2").contains('green')

});
```

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by using webpack aliases in the Cypress webpack config to intercept the node_module dependency.

So something like...

```js
// cypress/plugins/index.js

const path = require("path");
const { startDevServer } = require('@cypress/webpack-dev-server');

// your project's base webpack config
const webpackConfig = require('@vue/cli-service/webpack.config');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on("dev-server:start", (options) => {
    webpackConfig.resolve.alias["your-module"] = path.resolve(__dirname, "path/to/your-module-mock.js");

    return startDevServer({
      options,
      webpackConfig,
    })
  });
}
```

```js
// path/to/your-module-mock.js

let yourMock;

export function setupMockModule(...) {
  yourMock = {
    ...
  };
}

export default yourMock;
```

```js
// your-test.spec.js

import { setupMock } from ".../your-module-mock.js"

describe("...", () => {
  before(() => {
    setupMock(...);
  });

  it("...", () => {
    ...
  });
});
```